# Advantages of developer specific android phones over normal android phones

Tags: android

I am planning to buy new android phone to test android applications that is  best for developers at present context. What type of android phone should i choose? what advantages do i have if i buy android phones specially meant for development over normal phones?

Comment: The main factor that determines which phone to get for android development is the version. Preferable you'd want to buy a kitkat phone so you can access all the latest apis and such

Comment: You can develop & test applications using any device. If the android os is latest version, then it will be better. And make sure that you have enabled the developer options in Settings of the device. That will help you.

Comment: Currently i am using htc explorer which i rooted and used custom rom to upgrade to kitkat, but whenever i test my app it takes more than 30 secs to see result after runnning the application. Is it normal?

Comment: *"I doubt weather it's appropriate place to ask..."* - [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be better places to ask. I had a similar question closed at Android Enthusiasts ([MIPS tablet for testing?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82242/mips-tablet-for-testing)), so Software Recommendations might be more accommodating. Super User does not take smartphone questions, so you would have to ask for a tablet, not a phone, if you tried there.

Comment: Thanks , i would do that from now on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get whatever is the current Nexus phone.

The advantages of these for development are:

- you get a stock Android experience, without the distractions of manufacturer supplied launchers and customizations
- you get the best access to the latest versions of Android
- it's easy to get hold of right device driver to use them with adb
- custom ROMs support these devices well if you ever want to go that route

Having said that, if you are serious about developing for Android, then you are going to want a range of test devices - but starting with a Nexus phone and a Nexus tablet is the best recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't make any sense. An important part about developing for Android is testing on as many devices as possible. For the rest of the development process it's best to use a device running 4.0 or above. Testing on 2.2 and 2.3 is only necessary if you want to make your app compatible with those versions. As of August 12, 2014, 4.0 and above make up 85.7% of all devices anyway (see [Dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net)).

Beside the Android version, there are still cases where you need to develop on specific devices. But that's only for hardware reasons. For example, not all devices support NFC. So if your app is supposed to utilize NFC, you obviously have to get an appropriate device.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus phones are specifically designed for development and promotion of android.

```
Benefits: 

1) You get latest software updates.
2) Developer Previews
3) Stock Android which means there will be no mess up with sensors and stuff.
```